# randomly display triangle inside Raphael canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I want to randomly display a triangle inside a box (currently produced with Raphael). The whole triangle should always be inside the box. Let's imagine it is for an experiment where one has to click on the triangle as soon as possible after it is displayed. But you could easily imagine other scenarios in which one needs an image to be shown only inside a box.

```
<div id="area"></div>
var paper = Raphael("area",300,300);
```

An arbitrary triangle:

```
var triangle = paper.path("M 100,100 L 70,50 L 40, 100").attr({"fill":"green"});
```

Concerning circles, this becomes pretty easy because of the fact that there is a function, namely paper.circle() with given x and y coordinates and a radius. But with triangles there are three corners with x and y coordinates that have to be taken into account.

Any suggestions? Maybe a completely different approach?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bV9A/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the translate function on the triangle object. First you need to alter your path a little bit so the triangle is all the way in the upper left hand corner of the rectangle:

```
var triangle = paper.path("M 60,50 L 30,0 L 0, 50").attr({"fill":"green"});
```

Next use the tranlsate function to randomly translate your triangle:

```
triangle.translate(Math.random() * 240, Math.random() * 250);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bV9A/1/